# Change of state render previous state React

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to change the state of a component but it keep rendering the previous state.

From what I understood, the component is rendered before the state is getting saved and I need to use a callback function, except that I did not succeed.

Here is a simplified code of what I'm trying to do:

```
export default function ColorPick() {

  const [color, setColor] = useState('');
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState('blue');

   const handleColor = (event, newChoice) => {
    setChoice(newChoice)
    if(choice === 'blue'){
      setColor('blue')
    }else{
      setColor('red') 
    }
  };

  return (
    <select onChange={handleColor} value={choice}>
     <option value="red">Red</option>
     <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <h1>{color}</h1>
  );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `event` parameter which returns the selected value. Then your `handleColor` will look like this

```
const handleColor = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);

  if (event.target.value === "blue") {
    setColor("blue");
  } else {
    setColor("red");
  }
};

  <select onChange={handleColor}>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <h1>{color}</h1>
```

Then also you don't need to use the choice state

Codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/plants-forked-hy8uk2?file=/src/CategoryDisplay.jsx:1247-1402)

Answer (score 0):

when you assign an `onChange` method like this, the component (`<select>`) only sends *event* argument to it. If you debug your `handleColor` method, you will see that the *newChoice* argument is always undefined.

You can access select's current value with `event.target.value` and you can even get rid of the *choice* hook altogether.

```
function ColorPick() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("")

  const handleColor = (event) => {
    setColor(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={handleColor}>
        <option value='red'>Red</option>
        <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
      </select>
      <h1>{color}</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```